# Using .resx files in Console .Net Core 1.1 application

Tags: .net-core, console-application, asp.net-core-localization

I was trying to check some cool .Net Core 1.1 features, but in process I met an issue.

I tried to create a simple .NetCore Console application

[image]

I also created two a simple .resx resourse files in root directory with a string resourse.

I let console load the resourse and It was loaded successfully.

When I changed the **CultureInfo** and loaded the string again.

I expected, that the localized string will be loaded, but console showed **the same (English) default resourse**

Do I doing something wrong? I expected, that localization should work like in previous versions of .NET, but It didn't.

My sample code below:

```
        //default string loaded
        Console.WriteLine(AppResource.resourseText);
        Console.ReadLine();

        //changing CultureInfo
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs");
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("cs");
        CultureInfo cul = new CultureInfo("cs");

        //loading the localized string 3 different ways
        Console.WriteLine(AppResource.resourseText);
        Console.WriteLine(AppResource.ResourceManager.GetString("resourseText"));
        Console.WriteLine(AppResource.ResourceManager.GetString("resourseText", cul));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What is the version of Visual Studio? Maybe you are hitting this [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3396). I did a quick test with latest VS 2017 and it worked.

Comment: I upadated VS 2017 to latest and error is still there

Comment: How are loading the resources file? Can you share the project?

Comment: Resourses are set as "Embedded Resource". Here is also published test project [link](https://github.com/MDuzij/LocalizationTest)

Comment: You have a small typo on the cs resource file name. `AppResourse.cs.resx`. Hope this helps.

Comment: In .net core 2.0 there is the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install this package 
"[Microsoft.Extensions.Localization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization/)", then Your code above will work as You want. It has verified uisng .net core 2.0 and console app