# Retrieve string value from resource file in .NET Core 3.1 WinForms (need simple example)

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, resources, resx

I've looked all over and found many complex examples.  Really I just need to read a string from my resource file.  My old code (pre-.NET Core) doesn't work anymore.  Could someone please show me a simple example?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't dealt with Resource Files personally in .NET Core, but it does look like they are still supported.  I found this article: [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that links to a [sample project](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/3.x/Localization).

It may seem complicated but in the end it will hopefully make sense if we break it down.  If you take a look at that code, the important things are:

In [startup.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/3.x/Localization/Startup.cs) they add localization support:

```
...

services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

...

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new [] { "en-US", "fr" };
    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
});
```

In the controller they get the service via Dependency Injection ([HomeController.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/3.x/Localization/Controllers/HomeController.cs) for example):

```
private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;

public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
{
    _localizer = localizer;
}
```

From there they use it in the Action:

```
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = _localizer["Your application description page."];

    return View();
}
```

Or in the [View](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/3.x/Localization/Views/Home/About.cshtml):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["About"];
}
```

(Using it from the View is probably a much better way to do it).

The actual localization files are stored in the [Resources folder](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/3.x/Localization/Resources) as mentioned in the Startup.cs configuration.  You can see that they're organized by controller/view.

There is some more code in the `Startup.cs` file related to localization but it's not super clear which ones exactly you would need.  I would copy over all the localization related code from their into your app, and find out which ones are actually needed by removing sections *after* you get it working.

Comment: Thank you.  I saw someone mention the startup.cs before.  I don't have one.  Do you mean program.cs?

Comment: Also, this isn't an MVC app, so I'm not sure what to do with all that code.

Comment: Ah OK, so in an MVC app you would have Startup.cs which sets up a lot of things for the application.  If you have a similar setup in your Program.cs you could do it that way.  I found this q/a about using Localization from a console app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652521/using-resx-files-in-console-net-core-1-1-application

Hopefully that helps.